# IBM MQ syncpoint and dotnet

Tags: ibm-mq

When trying to use c# and ibm mq client (9.1.5), I want to use the syncpoint functionality.

```
var getMessageOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions();
getMessageOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions();
getMessageOptions.Options += MQC.MQGMO_WAIT + MQC.MQGMO_SYNCPOINT;
getMessageOptions.WaitInterval = 20000;  // 20 seconds wait
Hashtable props = new Hashtable();
props.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, "localhost");
props.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, "DOTNET.SVRCONN");
props.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, 3636);
MQQueueManager qm = new MQQueueManager("QM", props);
MQQueue queue = qm.AccessQueue("Q1", MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF);

try
{
    var message = new MQMessage();
    queue.Get(message, getMessageOptions);

    string messageStr = message.ReadString(message.DataLength);

    SaveTheMessageToAFile(messageStr);
    //qm.Commit();

}
catch (MQException e) when (e.Reason == 2033)
{
   // Report exceptions other than "no messages in the queue"
     Log.Information("No messages in the queue");   
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  Log.Error($"Exception when trying to capture a message from the queue: 
}
```

I would have expected to see the same message each time if i didn't call commit. Is there something that needs to be enabled on the queuemanager?

Comment: You would need to crash/kill your program or call rollback. Right now you are just holding a uncommitted message.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, I was shutting down correctly (queue.Close() and queueManager.Disconnect()). When i removed those, I can see the same message after multiple runs. If you put your response in as an answer, i will mark as accepted

Comment: Answer posted with some points to the docs on the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you are not issuing a `Commit()` or a `Backout()`, so at that point the message will just be in a uncommitted state.  If you were to then kill off your process the message would get rolled back to the queue.  As you mentioned in the comments if you call `Disconnect()`, in most cases this will implicitly commit uncommitted messages.

This is documented in the IBM MQ KC in a few pages:

[Reference>Developing applications reference>The IBM MQ .NET classes and interfaces>MQQueueManager.NET class](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q111270_.htm)

> **Disconnect();**
>
> ...
>
> **Generally, any work performed as part of a unit of work is committed.** However, if the unit of work is `managed by .NET`, the unit of work might be rolled back.

**NOTE:** `managed by .NET` means a Distributed transactions, not what you are doing.

[Developing applications>Developing .NET applications](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q029250_.htm)

> When you use the procedural interface, you disconnect from a queue manager by using the call **`MQDISC`**`( Hconn, CompCode, Reason)`, where `Hconn` is a handle to the queue manager.
>
> In the .NET interface, the queue manager is represented by an object of class MQQueueManager. You disconnect from the queue manager by calling the **`Disconnect()`** method on that class.

[Developing applications>Developing MQI applications with IBM MQ>Writing a procedural application for queuing>Committing and backing out units of work>Syncpoint considerations in IBM MQ applications](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q026800_.htm)

> Except on z/OS batch with RRS, **if a program issues the MQDISC call while there are uncommitted requests, an implicit syncpoint occurs.** *If the program ends **abnormally**, an implicit backout occurs.*